# Deleting historical pageviews for certain UserIds in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I am trying to Delete historical data for pageviews related to certain Test accounts. The testing team did a demo run for Automation scripts in March due to which Pageviews in month of march grew dramatically. The site owner wants this pageviews aggregated in March, not to be reflected on the Overview Report for Behavior or any other data about these test accounts in any other reports.

The final count in pageviews for last 6 months is 8674. We want to reduce this count by removing data of 4 test accounts used for automation test runs. We deleted the four test users but I see their old data is still aggregating to various reports. They saying this data will get deleted from GA servers by next deletion cycle.

But will it still be reflecting in reports like above mentioned Pageviews? If Yes, then how can I remove the data related to 4 test accounts from reports?

I am not expecting such steep hike in pageviews for any month. I want the pageview counts of four test accounts to be removed from this report.

Comment: Can you not apply a relevant filter at reporting time?

Comment: Apologies for late response. At reporting, their is no way I can filter pageviews for some specific accounts. I do have ClientIDs as custom dimension, but Behavior > Overview where I see Pageview metric, I can't filter them.